# Concatenating one dimensional numpyarrays with variable size numpy array in loop

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

```
nNumbers = [1,2,3]
baseVariables = ['a','b','c','d','e']

arr = np.empty(0)
    
    for i in nNumbers:
        x = np.empty(0)
        for v in baseVariables:
            x = np.append(x, y['result'][i][v])
            print(x)
        arr = np.concatenate((arr, x))
```

I have one Json input stored in y. need to filter some variables out of that json format. the above code works in that it gives me the output in an array, but it is only in a one dimensional array. I want the output in a two dimensional array like:

> [['q','qr','qe','qw','etc']['','','','','']['','','','','']]

I have tried various different ways but am not able to figure it out. Any feedback on how to get it to the desired output format would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Forget using arrays here.  Use list, and nested lists if needed.  Practice on small test cases if nesting lists confuses you.

Comment: lists are slower than numpy arrays, it needs to be as quick as possible so that is the reason for using numpy arrays

Comment: Some things are faster with lists.  `list.append` is one of those.  Arrays used the right way can be faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A correct basic Python way of making a nested list of strings:

```
In [57]: nNumbers = [1,2,3]
    ...: baseVariables = ['a','b','c','d','e']

In [58]: alist = []
    ...: for i in nNumbers:
    ...:     blist = []
    ...:     for v in baseVariables:
    ...:         blist.append(v+str(i))
    ...:     alist.append(blist)
    ...:     

In [59]: alist
Out[59]: 
[['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e1'],
 ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'e2'],
 ['a3', 'b3', 'c3', 'd3', 'e3']]
```

That can be turned into an array if necessary - though `numpy` doesn't provide much added utility for strings:

```
In [60]: np.array(alist)
Out[60]: 
array([['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e1'],
       ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'e2'],
       ['a3', 'b3', 'c3', 'd3', 'e3']], dtype='<U2')
```

Or in a compact list comprehension form:

```
In [61]: [[v+str(i) for v in baseVariables] for i in nNumbers]
Out[61]: 
[['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e1'],
 ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'e2'],
 ['a3', 'b3', 'c3', 'd3', 'e3']]
```

You are starting with lists!  And making strings!  And selecting items from a JSON, with `y['result'][i][v]`.  None of that benefits from using `numpy`, especially not the repeated use of `np.append` and `np.concatenate`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide an example of JSON? It sounds like you basically want to

1. Filter the JSON
2. Flatten the JSON
   Depending on what your output example means, you might want to not filter, but replace certain values with empty values, is that correct?

Please note that Pandas has very powerfull out-of-the-box options to handle, and in particular, flatten JSONs. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-json-reader. An approach could be to first load in Pandas and filter it from there. Flattening a JSON can also be done by iterating over it like so:

```
def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(y)
    return out
```

I got this code from: https://towardsdatascience.com/flattening-json-objects-in-python-f5343c794b10. The author explains some challenges of flattening JSON. Of course, you can put some `if` statement into the function for your filtering need. I hope this can get you started at least!

Comment: the reason i dont use pandas is because it adds another input and the aim of the code is to to execute as quick as possible. The JSON input is basically over 300 items which all have 20 variables in them. The main output is to get 3 of the items and get only 5 variables for each. So yes, i do need to filter, but i am not replacing values with zero, im simply discarding them by not using them. I appreciate the reply but unfortunately it does not help. I also use numpy as it is faster in handling than the normal lists.

Comment: Can you give an example of the JSON? Is the name of the key enough for you to evaluate whether you want to keep the value? Do you just need a simple traversal algorithm that returns certain key-value pairs?

Comment: json file cosists of two catogories: value and result. Only interesting the result parts, for that i use y['result']. then the result part consist of 300ish entries similar to this: {'Name':'John', City':'Los Angeles','State':'CA', 'hobbies':'Music'} it goes on for rouglhy 20 items. Im only interested in 3 of the 300 entries. and only interested in 5 out of 20 items. So i need to filter it down and add them to an numpy array. I want these three numpy arrays into one - two dimensional numpy array.